# How to scope querySelector to component in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have this component, andI would like to do some manipulations on its children elements in ways that are not feasible in a state-driven way. So I would like to use a statement and a `querySelector` in it. But how can I scope it to the element? There are multiple instances of the component in the page, so a class or id is not possible. How can I achieve this?

Here's a simplified code:

```js
    <script>
      export let value = ''
      export let readonly = true

      $: if (value && !readonly){
      // selects the first element in the document, not the one from this instance 
      const nd = document.querySelector('.forminput')
      // Do something with nd
    }
   </script>

    <textarea bind:value wrap="soft" rows="1" class="forminput"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `bind:this` to assign an element to a variable

```html
<script>
   let wrapper;
</script>

<div bind:this="{wrapper}"></div>
```

now you can use `wrapper` as if you would have gotten it from a querySelector

Comment: Answer not clear, please add context.

Answer (score 11):

Building on the answer by Stephane Vanraes, use `bind:this` to bind the top-level element of your component to a variable and then use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` on that root element. For example:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  let root;
  let text;
  let value;

  onMount(() => {
     const nd = root.querySelectorAll('.forminput');
     // Do something with nd, such as adding event listeners, styles, etc.
  });
</script>

<div bind:this={root}>
  <input type="text" bind:value class="forminput"/>
  <textarea bind:text wrap="soft" rows="1" class="forminput"></textarea>
</div>
```

You can then get the full power of `querySelector` scoped to your component.

Note that `root` is properly bound only after the component has been mounted, thus the encapsulation of the code in the `onMount` function.

Comment: This was useful for doing a simple port of a native HTML page to Svelte. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO as it does not actually answer the original question "How do I scope `querySelector` to an element/component?". While Stephane's answer is extremely useful and in most situations the recommended way there are times it won't work, i.e. bind a to a list inside an `{#each ...}` block that changes.

Comment: @Jadams you can bind in a list using the index or a unique prop `bind:this={inputs[id]` with inputs an array or object in your script tag