# Components affect each other in Svelte

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner learning the web.

While I was studying the web, I realized that if the id is the same among the components, it has an effect each others.

I know I need to use a unique id, but I don't know how to use in css.

I linked the [demo page](https://svelte.dev/repl/ebec7313d94d410192075d8d77e3d765?version=3.46.4).

The text may be weird, because i'm using a translator. I'm sorry.

Comment: What exactly do you want? post your original language in the comment we may be able to speak with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because you call the `querySelector` on the whole document which contains all the elements. So it wil find 2 elements with the id `testDiv` and because it doesn't know which one you want it just takes the first. You can fix this by not using `document.querySelector` but binding the element itself to a variable whitin the component so that you don't have to find the html element but have a reference inside the component that is always pointing to the correct element. Example:

https://svelte.dev/repl/cfa458ef45de466aa9421705f49cc95e?version=3.46.4

Here is also a related question if you want to read into it more: [How to scope querySelector to component in Svelte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598941/how-to-scope-queryselector-to-component-in-svelte)